# How does collections.sort work without implementing comparable?

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I was researching the best way to sort an arraylist. I found this method which seemed very unusual to me. I was able to sort without implementing comparable to the class. Also what does the '->' do? Is it just a pointer?

```
Collections.sort(readings, (p1, p2) -> p1.getHeading().compareTo(p2.getHeading()));
```

Comment: It is implementing comparable :P ... covered in a huge pile of syntactic sugar.

Comment: The thing with the `->` is a [lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: If you do not have a comparator sort would use [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) or `compareTo` from `Compareable` interface. In your case you use sort with a lambda expression as a `Comparator` interface implementation (by using `Compareable` from `getHeading()` which is probably a string.

Comment: @Fildor  I have always assumed the class must "implement comparable" in order to be able to use .sort

Comment: @eckes thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Eran actually [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) uses a Comparator not a Compareable (the lambda expression implements this by falling back to the Compareable from getHeading() to implement it)

Comment: @eckes I was sure the OP was asking about Comparator. My bad

Comment: @RMRiver Yes, there is a lot going on "under the hood" here. Lambdas are still sometimes a mystery to me, too :) Couldn't actually have explained it as well as eckes out of the sleeve. I have to look this stuff up, too.